Using a powershell script to read a excel document and insert into sharepoint. How do i read from second sheet?
My script so far can read from the first sheet of the excel document, but i need it to read from the second sheet. Any suggestions?

#Read the Excel Data and change path accordingly
$data = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Test\ExcelDoc.xlsm"
#Declare Site URL and List names
$SiteUrl = "https://Consato.sharepoint.com/sites/Stage"
# Update with the internal name of the SharePoint list.
$ListName = "DataList"
#Initiate a connection to SharePoint site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Interactive
try {
    ForEach($record in $data) {
        Write -Host "Adding record $($record.'Record Series')"
        #Add List Items - Map with Internal Names of the Fields!.Below you define a custom object @ {}for each record and update the SharePoint list.
        Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values @{
            "Title" = $($record.'VALUE');
            
        };
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}



found the answer, i can use
$data = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Test\ExcelDoc.xlsm" -Worksheet nameofsheet
#Declare Site URL and List names
$SiteUrl = "https://Consato.sharepoint.com/sites/Stage"
# Update with the internal name of the SharePoint list.
$ListName = "DataList"
#Initiate a connection to SharePoint site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Interactive
try {
    ForEach($record in $data) {
        Write -Host "Adding record $($record.'Record Series')"
        #Add List Items - Map with Internal Names of the Fields!.Below you define a custom object @ {}for each record and update the SharePoint list.
        Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values @{
            "Title" = $($record.'VALUE');
            
        };
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}


